# Synonimze [origin] for [provenance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Anyone want to create [origin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) as a synonym for [provenance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provenance)?

I think it's much easier to find.

Comment: +1 ....I would do it myself, but don't have score of 5 in [tag:provenance] :(